# How can I match columns with each other?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

[image]

How can I make both columns match each other?  I am using listView to show the following.  But they are not matching each other.  Following is my xml code for the activity:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="60dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:id="@+id/englishTextView"
    android:text="Kutta"
    android:background="@color/green" />

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/japaneseTextView"
    android:text="Dog"
    android:background="@color/yellow" />
```

Comment: Just a comment-  don't use a a 1 dp view to space things.  Its wasteful of resources.  Set a layout_marginEnd="1dp" on the element before it instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:lines="5"
        android:id="@+id/englishTextView"
        android:text="Kutta"
        android:background="@color/green"/>

<View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:lines="5"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/japaneseTextView"
    android:text="Dog"
    android:background="@color/yellow"/>
```

Try out this

Comment: thanks brother it worked for me. I wonder how u understood my question. But thanks for your help